# How chunk file upload works

Tags: file-upload, chunking

I am working on file upload and really wandering how actually chunk file upload works.

While i understand client sends data in small chunks to server instead of complete file at once. But i have few questions on this:-

1. For browser to divide and send whole file into chunks, Will it read complete file to its memory? If yes, then again there will me chances of memory leak and browser crash for big files(say > 10GB)
2. How cloud application like google drive droopbox handles such big files upload?
3. If multiple files are selected to upload and all have size grater than 5-10 GB, Does browser keep all files into memory then send it chunk by chunk?

Answer (score -3):

Not sure if you're still looking for answer, I been in your position recently, and here's what I've come up with, hope it helps: Deal chunk uploaded files in php

During uploading, If you can print out the request from the backend, you shall see three parameters: _chunkNumber, _totalSize and _chunkSize, with these parameters it's easy to decide whether this chunk is the last piece, if it is, assemble all of the pieces as a whole shouldn't be hard.

As for javascript side, ng-file-upload has a setting named "resumeChunkSize" where you can enable chunk mode and setup the chunk size.